# Error: An unexpected error has occurred. While trying to deploy "firebase deploy" in terminal, in a cloud functions project (python)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the recurrent problem where when I try to perform a firebase deploy for cloud functions, I have an unexpected error according to the terminal. Below is my code.
I have already installed the latest version of firebase_functions, but the log insists in "module not found"

```
PS C:\Users\thirs\Documents\FirebaseProjects\v2Firebase> firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'databasebackendtesting'...

i  deploying firestore, functions
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
+  cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
PS C:\Users\thirs\Documents\FirebaseProjects\v2Firebase>
```

And here is my debug firebase log

```
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.026Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/databasebackendtesting/configs [none]
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.297Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/databasebackendtesting/configs 200
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.297Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/databasebackendtesting/configs {}
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.298Z] Customer code is not Node
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.298Z] Validating python source
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.298Z] Building python source
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.299Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.303Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="C:\Users\thirs\Documents\FirebaseProjects\v2Firebase\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","python.exe","-c","\"import firebase_functions; import os; print(os.path.dirname(firebase_functions.__file__))\""]
[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.376Z] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.377Z] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_functions'

[debug] [2023-06-05T18:47:36.407Z] Error: spawn "C:\Users\thirs\Documents\FirebaseProjects\v2Firebase\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\thirs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\thirs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\thirs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I just wanted to deploy the functions, please help :)

Comment: The error you should be paying the most attention to is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_functions'"

Comment: but I cant understand why it cant find it

Comment: even though I have realized the pip install of firebase_functions locally and globally

Comment: Ideally your question should contain enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the error.  We can't see your source code or how you set up your project, which makes it hard to know what's going on.  I suggest sharing the steps you take *from a fresh project* that anyone can follow that eventually lead to the error.  Start with `firebase init`.

Comment: ok, i´ll do a more elaborate question, thankyou very much for the advice, this is my first time asking for a question